# Accessing the sidebar state using bs4Dash

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements, sidebar, bs4dash

Using `{shinydashboard}`, we can access the state of the sidebar (collapsed or not) with `input$sidebarCollapsed` :

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(), 
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    textOutput("res")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$res <- renderText({
    if (input$sidebarCollapsed) {
      "Sidebar is collapsed"
    } else {
      "Sidebar is expanded"
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

However with `{bs4dash}`, this does not work :

```
library(shiny)
library(bs4Dash)

ui <- bs4Dash::dashboardPage(
  bs4Dash::dashboardHeader(), 
  bs4Dash::dashboardSidebar(),
  bs4Dash::dashboardBody(
    shiny::textOutput("res")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$res <- shiny::renderText({
    if (input$sidebarCollapsed) {
      "Sidebar is collapsed"
    } else {
      "Sidebar is expanded"
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The app returns `Error: argument is of length zero`.

What am I missing ? Is there any alternative ? Accessing the sidebar state is useful for me, so that I can hide some widgets when the sidebar is minified (in order to only keep the sidebar icons visible and not widgets such as selectInputs which appear messy when minified).

I have also tried changing to `sidebarMinified` or some other hopeless attempts...

Note that I can also use `shiny::conditionalPanel()` with the condition written as `'input.sidebarCollapsed'` but the result is the same.

Thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was just wondering the same thing and, upon searching the [bs4Dash how-to-start guide](https://bs4dash.rinterface.com/articles/step-by-step.html), found the answer.

> *id* is used by the updateSidebar() function to programmatically toggle the sidebar on the server. input$ indicates the state of the sidebar: TRUE means open and FALSE means collapsed/minified.

So, if you set the id of your sidebar to be 'my_sidebar', then you can access the state of sidebar with `input$my_sidebar`.